# GOLANG WebSocket как с клиента на golang отправить сообщение на сервер

Tags: golang, websocket

Я использую клиент и сервер отсюда:
github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/echo

=================

UPD:

Немножко поменяю вопрос, чтобы было понятно. Сейчас клиент шлет такие сообщения и сервер их принимает
[image: клиент и сервер]

**Вопрос: Как мне отправить не тики, а сообщение "Hello World"?**

**Код клиента:**

```
// Copyright 2015 The Gorilla WebSocket Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style
// license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

//go:build ignore
// +build ignore

package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

var addr = flag.String("addr", "localhost:8080", "http service address")

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    log.SetFlags(0)

    interrupt := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(interrupt, os.Interrupt)

    u := url.URL{Scheme: "ws", Host: *addr, Path: "/echo"}
    log.Printf("connecting to %s", u.String())

    c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("dial:", err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    done := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        defer close(done)
        for {
            _, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("read:", err)
                return
            }
            log.Printf("recv: %s", message)
        }
    }()

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            return
        case t := <-ticker.C:
            err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(t.String()))
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("write:", err)
                return
            }
        case <-interrupt:
            log.Println("interrupt")

            // Cleanly close the connection by sending a close message and then
            // waiting (with timeout) for the server to close the connection.
            err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.CloseMessage, websocket.FormatCloseMessage(websocket.CloseNormalClosure, ""))
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("write close:", err)
                return
            }
            select {
            case <-done:
            case <-time.After(time.Second):
            }
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Грубо говоря меня нужен клиент websocket на golang который отправит на сервер "Hello World"

Answer (score 0):

Использую в итоге этот клиент, тут хотя бы понятно как хелло ворд отправить:
https://github.com/sacOO7/GoWebsocket/blob/master/examples/gowebsocket/main.go

```
    package main

import (
    "log"
    "github.com/sacOO7/gowebsocket"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
)

func main() {
    interrupt := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(interrupt, os.Interrupt)

    socket := gowebsocket.New("ws://echo.websocket.org/");
    socket.ConnectionOptions = gowebsocket.ConnectionOptions{
        //Proxy: gowebsocket.BuildProxy("http://example.com"),
        UseSSL:         false,
        UseCompression: false,
        Subprotocols:   [] string{"chat", "superchat"},
    }

    socket.RequestHeader.Set("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch")
    socket.RequestHeader.Set("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8")
    socket.RequestHeader.Set("Pragma", "no-cache")
    socket.RequestHeader.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36")

    socket.OnConnectError = func(err error, socket gowebsocket.Socket) {
        log.Fatal("Recieved connect error ", err)
    };
    socket.OnConnected = func(socket gowebsocket.Socket) {
        log.Println("Connected to server");
    };
    socket.OnTextMessage = func(message string, socket gowebsocket.Socket) {
        log.Println("Recieved message  " + message)
    };
    socket.OnPingReceived = func(data string, socket gowebsocket.Socket) {
        log.Println("Recieved ping " + data)
    };
    socket.OnDisconnected = func(err error, socket gowebsocket.Socket) {
        log.Println("Disconnected from server ")
        return
    };
    socket.Connect()

    i := 0
    for (i < 10) {
        socket.SendText("This is my sample test message")
        i++
    }

    for {
        select {
        case <-interrupt:
            log.Println("interrupt")
            socket.Close()
            return
        }
    }
}
```